# DropzoneJs in Asp.net core application not uploading files

Tags: asp.net, dropzone.js

I am trying to use DropzoneJS to upload multiple photos to a webapplication.

The Upload view contains following

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <form action="/Upload"
          class="dropzone"
          id="dropzoneJsForm"
          style="background-color:#00BFFF"></form>
</div>
```

And the Upload controller contains this

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file, IHostingEnvironment _environment)
{
    var uploads = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "uploads");
    if (file.Length > 0)
    {
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, file.FileName), FileMode.Create))
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

When I run the application in debug mode and add files I see the progressbar and the checkmark indicating success. But no files has been uploaded in the upload folder in wwwroot.

I have app.UseStaticFiles() in the Configure method.

Target framework: .Net Core 2.0

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Professional latest version

Comment: When you debug, is `file.Length` actually `> 0` ?

Comment: Yes the file is sent to the server. I found the mistake. A stupid beginner mistake. When I changed the name of the controller method to Index it worked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the mistake. A stupid beginner mistake. When I changed the name of the controller method to Index it worked.

Comment: That is not a scientific answer

Answer (score -1):

```
<webconfig>
<system.web> 
<httpRuntime  maxRequestLength="15360" requestLengthDiskThreshold="15360"/> 
</system.web>
```

'consider using fileupload='multiple' attribute on control